# Display Graph in Titanium iOS

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

In my app, i need to display the status of the feedback by a **Graph**(chart) view.

Is *webview* is need?

I tried ***RGraph*** framework, which is showing errors for me, how to use this framework?

Are they're anyother ways their to achieve this?

**Thanks in Advance**!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this library utilizes a canvas, which you'll need a webview to display on.  Some possibly helpful reading material on displaying charts:
[Display Charts with Titanium](http://www.techjunkie.com/displaying-charts-with-titanium-appcelerator/)